# Call a remote address from Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, call

I have to call a remote service which expects me to send some parameters along with the URL, i.e.: `HTTP://HOST:PORT/APPNAME/privado/loginAction.do?idioma=ES&CssSize=1&urlRespuesta=SOMEOTHERURL`

How should I make the call from a controller in Spring MVC??

Obviously the host is not the same as the one in which my app is deployed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the end I did it somewhat like you suggest but this way:

```
return "redirect:/http://blablabla.com/loginAction.do"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the *controller* to make the call, and not send a redirect, then you could use [Apache Commons HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/), or if the other service is RESTful you could use Spring's [RESTTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html).

Comment: RESTTemplate this is what I looked for ! Tnx !

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can use

```
response.sendRedirect("remote_server_url");
```

Its fine if host is not the same on which app is deployed.